# CSS flex column wrap with no height pre-set and forcing of a number of columns

Tags: html, css, flexbox

Example code:
https://jsfiddle.net/z7ybks9u/2/

**Motivation**: I would like to **force a 3 column layout**, WITH support for fixed width but variable height DIVS, wit layout efficiency that will not expose large "whitespace holes" between items. Since the number of elements is unknown, **I cannot limit the height of the flex container**.

**Problem**: without forcing the height of the flex container, I cannot see more than one column, as it just utilizes the vertical space it needs to fit all items in one column.

What I am forced to do:

```
gallery-height {

      display: flex;
      flex-direction: column;
      flex-wrap: wrap;
      align-content: center;
      max-height: 700px;   <-----  NEED TO DO THAT TO SEE COLUMNS BUT I HAVE TO SUPPORT UNKNOWN NBR OF ELEMENTS
    }
```

Comment: duplicate of : https://stackoverflow.com/q/44377343/8620333

Comment: This is extremely hard to implement yourself. Have you checked out any masonry packages for this?

Comment: not yet, just wanted to make sure that modern CSS has no solution for something as trivial as I mentioned.

Comment: Turns out there is, based on that answer you got down there. I learned something new today

Comment: learned something too

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Dropping the Flex container in favor of `column-count` might help: https://jsfiddle.net/69nmwqag/

```
.gallery-height {
  column-count: 3;
}
```

Then I dropped `width: 30%;` on `.img`.